# How to configure Gradle task sequences

Tags: android, gradle

My app has many different variants serving different purpose.
The most important variant is *variant1* and the second most important *variant2*.
I want to trigger building of *variant2* every time I run unit tests for *variant1*.

`./gradlew testVariant1UnitTest` should execute the following:

1. `.gradlew assembleVariant2`
2. `./gradlew testVariant1UnitTest`

I've read [Gradle's documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks) and tried this in my **build.gradle** file:
`testVariant1UnitTest.dependsOn assembleVariant2`
And I got:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'testGrabtaxi2DebugUnitTest' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

What am I missing?

Versions:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-12-20 15:45:23 UTC
Revision:     10ed9dc355dc39f6307cc98fbd8cea314bdd381c

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_144 (Oracle Corporation 25.144-b01)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.13.2 x86_64
```

Comment: Do you have 2  `build.gradle` files? in your two variants?

Comment: No, there is only one build.gradle file for the module "app" which contains both variants mentioned @DanielTaub

Answer (score 1):

You can reach your goal in that way :

```
task customTask(dependsOn: assembleVariant2){
    doLast{
        testVariant1UnitTest
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @DanielTaub, but I'm getting `Could not get unknown property 'assembleVariant2' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project`